# centering a website in IE alone

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

when tried centering the [website](http://vandabaths.com/uk/gallery/)

I tried using

```
* { margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align:center; }

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;              
}
```

But the problem is all the text inside the website gets center aligned, please help. I currently reverted it back and took off text-align:center; and text-align:left; from the live site. Please help.

many thanks.

Comment: try adding display: block;

Comment: Put `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `body,html{height:100%,width:100%;}`.

Comment: http://vandabaths.com/uk/gallery/  == 41 Errors, 57 warning(s) and NO <doctype> !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this rule

```
#container * { text-align:left; }
```

and change `#container` as:

```
#container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I suggest to remove `text-align:center;` from the selector `all (*)` and align text more specific

Comment: thanks a lot, I have one more problem, height: 200px; is not working on [link](http://vandabaths.com/uk/products/)this page... can some one help me please

Comment: `height:200px;` on what. Maybe you should start a new question

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:left;              
}
```

This should center the container and in the container you have the whole website in.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `<!DOCTYPE html>`
the `margin: auto` will also work for ie to center divs.

a side note. your html code is screwed up. you have some *garbage* in front of your `doctype`